# Sampling of groceries

Tags: sampling

I need some statistical advice. I am planning a marketing research to test if gluten free food is more expensive than regular food. I know it is, I want to show just how much more expensive it is. I have no problem going to several shops and "sample" all the products they have. Theoretically, I could sample all the products in the country, or at least almost all the products, since the variety is not very large. Each product is being sold in many shops, in different prices. My question is how should I plan the sampling process, should I sample all possible products and use descriptive statistics only ? should I take a sample ? how will I choose the sample, it won't be random obviously ? should I sample each product from various shops and average the price ? same question is regarded the paired product, the normal one. I know the basic sampling methods: random, stratified, cluster. I can't figure out how to sample in this case.